# Why data binding?

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

Please check [ListView Data Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding). You can find following code in XAML file:

```
  <ListView x:Name="EmployeeView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
```

But if you remove ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}", it is still working because there is EmployeeView.ItemsSource = employees in c# file. What's the point to do ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}?

Please advise. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The first two examples achieve the same thing with different approaches - look at the text between the code sections ("The equivalent C# code is:")